# Guild members without bots always 1

Tags: javascript, discord.js

I'm using

```js
let real_members = interaction.guild.members.cache.filter((member) => !member.user.bot).size;
```

to get all members excluding the bots on a server, but this somehow always returns 1. (Slash command)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fetch all the GuildMember's first and access the returning collection, then sweep (remove) all the members who are bots.

```js
let real_members;
interaction.guild.members.fetch().then(all_members => {
   real_members = all_members.sweep(member => member.user.bot);
});

console.log(real_members.size);
```

Ensure you have `Intents.FLAGS.GUILD_MEMBERS` included in your client's intents aswell as enabled in your Discord developer portal

Discord.JS [Collection Utility Functions](https://discordjs.guide/additional-info/collections.html#extra-utilities)

Comment: Thanks, but how do I access real_members to use it in an embed?

Comment: If you prefer, you can convert the Collection into an array by doing `const real_members = [...all_members.sweep(member => member.user.bot)];` Or you can view the Collection guide I've linked in my answer

Comment: When I now try to do `console.log(real_members)` outside of the function(?), it's not working because it says that it's not defined. I tried a few things, but they did not work. Do you know how to do it?

Comment: Because `real_members` is defined inside the function. If you want it to be global I have provided an example

Comment: I don't know why, but the value is undefined. But I'll open a new question since that isn't related to the problem of this post. Anyway, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try using ".fetch" so:

```
interaction.guild.members.fetch()
.then ((members) => {
    const AmountOfMembers = members.filter((member) => !member.user.bot).size
})
```

CODE IS NOT TESTED

To be able to access it outside either define variable outside or turn it into a function and return the value.

```
function getMembers (interaction) {
    interaction.guild.members.fetch()
    .then ((members) => {
        members.filter((member) => !member.user.bot).size
        .then((Amount) => {
        return Amount
        })
    }) 
};


const AmountOfMembers = getMembers(interaction);
```

Just pass it your interaction.

Comment: Sadly not working :/

Comment: I cannot access the variable outside of the function. How do I do that?

Comment: @EckigerLuca Check edit

Comment: This now returns undefined. How do I turn it into a function then? Just a return statement isn't working

Comment: This sadly still returns undefined. Its working inside the function

Comment: @EckigerLuca share your code that your using please. Maybe update your question with it